# Compiling Fortran 77 with an external library using a Makefile

Tags: makefile, compilation, fortran, dependencies

I have main program `Engine.f` that calls functions/external in `LIB.f`. 
Unlike C++ and Java there is no include in the main program so it will be possible to compile.

How does my Fortran comiler know that there is another library which I use?

I'm using photran from Eclipse.

The MAKE file:

```
.PHONY: all clean

# Change this line if you are using a different Fortran compiler
FORTRAN_COMPILER = gfortran

all: src/Engine.f
    $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -O2 -g \
        -o bin/Engine.exe \
        src/Engine.f

clean:
    rm -f bin/Engine.exe *.mod
```

errors that I get when I compile:

```
undefined reference to (name of function in **LIB.f**)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.PHONY: all clean
all: Engine.exe

# Change this line if you are using a different Fortran compiler
FORTRAN_COMPILER = gfortran
FORTRAN_FLAGS=-O2 -g

%.o: src/%.f
    $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) -c $<

Engine.exe: Lib.o Engine.o
    $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) \
        -o bin/Engine.exe \
        Lib.o Engine.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

In FORTRAN 77, the compiler "just" needs the function to be supplied in a `.o` file at link time. You can test the Makefile below, it should do what you want.

Modern versions of Fortran use module files to structure libraries, if you ever upgrade to that.

Comment: yes you are Right @pierre de Buyl
when I compile it I get this:
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
**** This mean it doesn't compile at all. Right?

Comment: I forgot to reinstate a make target. Try `make Engine.exe`

Comment: I added a "all" target again

Comment: I get this:
make all  (new line)
gfortran "O2 -g" -c src/LIB.f  (new line)
gfortran: error: O2 -g: No such file or directory  (new line)
make: *** [Makefile:17: LIB.o] Error 1  (new line)

16:43:01 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 360ms)  (new line)
line 17 is: $(FORTRAN_COMPILE ...

Comment: I missed a space, and the quotes are wrong. I edited the makefile.

Comment: yup that's better, now I get: "make: *** [Makefile:17: LIB.o] Error 1" - where line 17 is   $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) -c $<

Comment: This is surprising now. The code "box" on Stack Overflow is not very tab friendly. Did you make sure that all indented lines in the Makefile start with a tab and not spaces? Else it won't work at all.

Comment: Kindly, yes I did make sure it starts with TAB where it need to be. I will do some reading and then I will update here what happens.

Comment: The error occurs when make tries to build `Lib.o`, any whitespace error below `%.o: src/%.f` might cause an error.

Comment: After compiling the whole program runs as should be.
Thanks a lot for help here Mr. @Pierre de Buyl